# Passing two Ranges as a parameters and executing though excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, parameter-passing

I am trying to make a function that pass two range as a parameters, the code look something like this:

```
    Function WhatEverFunction(range1 As Range, range2 As Range) As Integer

         Dim column As ingeter
         column = range1.Column
         'make some stuff with the column

         WhatEverFunction = range1.Value + range2.Value
    End Function
```

This is how I execute the code and pass the parameters:
[image]

But this is the result:
[image]

Comment: you have spelt integer wrong. Also, better to declare as Long. Also, don't call a variable column.

Comment: What is an `ingeter` supposed to be? Also -- why not use `Double`? Note that if the unspecified "stuff" that you are going to do to with column involves modifying the column as a side-effect, then you wouldn't be able to use it as a user defined function.

Comment: Yes I wrote Integer wrong, thanks for point the error

Answer (score 1):

Here are some of those corrections. Also, you are really just doing SUM so maybe consider the following:

```
 Public Function WhatEverFunction(ByVal range1 As Range, ByVal range2 As Range) As Long

         Dim myColumn As Long
         myColumn = range1.column
         'make some stuff with the column

         WhatEverFunction = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(range1, range2)
    End Function
```

Note @john Coleman's comment about what a udf cannot do. To be explicit, a UDF returns something to the cell it is placed in.

And your local settings might require  `WhatEverFunction = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(range1; range2)`

Comment: Which to be honest makes the whole thing really, at present, become the existing Sum function in Excel.

Comment: Maybe, but this does not answer my question, in fact what I need is work with the column

Comment: It did answer your question. The error was due to the spelling. I just tried to be helpful with some additional pointers.

Comment: Yes I know, but I just write some code to show what I need, just skip the full code, but I think the true problem is I am not able to write some values in some cells from a function

Comment: No. A udf returns something to the cell it is placed in which is why I also referenced at John Coleman’s comment. I dealt with error as shown. Also, handled the fact integer risks overflow. Using SUM is optimised for ranges so better than + value. You need to pass by val the arguments and calling a variable column which is also an object in vbe can cause confusion if not for the compiler for you.

Comment: I have edited to make the UDF purpose more explicit.